# Invoke the methods of the assembly is created by reflection from its owner in .NET

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I  know  how to create some object by reflection and pass some arguments.

```
Dim assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
Dim control As Object

assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("WpfControlLibrary1")
control = assembly.CreateInstance("WpfControlLibrary1.Main")

control.Maximize("true")
```

My question is if there is an approach to get info from "the control" into "the owner" of that "control".

So I guess should be some way to have bidirectional interaction between the owner and created assembly.

For example within some Timer I want get the states of the "control" periodically.

```
foreach(...)
{

var state = control.GetState(); // ????? Is it possible ?
Sleep(10000);

}
```

[Here we can see how to pass the parameters](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/98148)

**So what I need is to get back some returned object up.**

Thank you in advance for any useful clue my brothers and sisters in programming!

Comment: Are you sure that the row `control.Maximize("true")` will work?

Comment: I meant to pass some object like a argument. But yeah ... it works. This is the real code. The point is that Visual Studio doesn't show the  "Maximize" method after the dot. :) But It works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke method defined on classes in another assembly, you need something like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("OtherAssembly");
Type controlType = assembly.GetType("OtherAssembly.OtherAssemblyClass");
object control = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);

controlType.InvokeMember("SetFullName", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, 
                         control, new object[] { "FirstName", "LastNameski" });
```

This will invoke the method `SetFullName` of the class `OtherAssemblyClass` of the assembly `OtherAssembly` on the object `control`, using the parameters `"FirstName"` and `"LastNameski"`

```
object result = controlType.InvokeMember("GetFullName", 
                            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, control, null);
```

This will invoke a method called `GetFullName` on that same object, which accepts no parameters (hence the last `null` in the call) and returns a string.

```
Console.WriteLine(result.GetType().FullName);
```

This will print out `"System.String"`

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This will print out `"FirstName LastNameski"`.

---

in the example, the other assembly contains this class:

```
namespace OtherAssembly
{
  public class OtherAssemblyClass
  {
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public void SetFullName(string first, string last)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer! It looks good. Sorry, Is there a clue where I can find it under MSDN?